# spark_write_csv doesn't work anymore (with Sparklyr)

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

spark_write_csv function doesn't work anymore, maybe since I upgraded the Spark version. Could someone help please?

Here is the code example, and the error message below:

```
    library(sparklyr)
    library(dplyr)
    spark_conn <- spark_connect(master = "local")
    iris <- copy_to(spark_conn, iris, overwrite = TRUE)
    spark_write_csv(iris, path = "iris.csv")

Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
```

Comment: I've got the same issue with sparklyr 1.7.8 (latest sparklyr version as of today), Spark 3.3.0 and Hadoop 2.